Qt 6.7 ODBC MSSQL Connection String doesn't work
I am currently trying to establish a connection to an MS SQL Server using the new Qt 6.7 version @ Windowa 10 with QtCreator. The connection string worked fine with Qt 6.6, but now I am getting the error “The data source name was not found and no default driver specified” in 6.7. What could be the reason for this?
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC",dbName);

db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL SERVER};Server=SERVERADRESS;Database=DBNAME;Uid=USER;Port=1433;Pwd=PASSWORD");
db.open(); //failed in QT 6.7

I have read the Changelog for Version 6.7, but doesn't find any Change, that cause my Problem.
It can't be a Windows ODBC Problem, i think,, like the other Posts, it show up only in Qt 6.7, all Qt Versions below 6.7 work with that Connection String.

Aside... Port isn't an ODBC Driver for SQL Server connection string property. If you need to specify a port number (i.e.: one that's not the 1433 default port) then you include it in the Server property with a comma separator. e.g.: for an instance lisenting on 3341 you'd use Server=ServerNameOrIpAddress,3341;

@Marc  This is a bug in 6.7, apparently fixed in 6.7.1.  See https://forum.qt.io/topic/155973/qodbc-does-not-work-in-6-7/3 in Qt forum.
Sadly also shows how unhelpful the "This question already has answers here:" sometimes are here on SO.
